# why sizeof is printing 8 instead of 12

Tags: c, memory, sizeof

I was doing a simple program of a struct,allocated memory for the struct.name for 12 characters(line 14) but the print of sizeof(p[i].name) (line 32) is showing 8 instead of 12. Why is doing **that**?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>

typedef struct person{
    char *name;
    uint32_t age; 
}person_;
int main()
{
    person_ p[3];
    uint32_t i,j;
    for(i = 0;i<3;i++){
        p[i].name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);
        if(p[i].name == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"Error allocating memory\n");
            for(j = 0;j<i;j++){
                free(p[i].name);
            }
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0;i<3;i++){
        if(fgets(p[i].name,sizeof(p[i].name),stdin) == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"Error reading string\n");
            exit(2);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%s",p[i].name);
        printf("sizeof(%d)",sizeof(p[i].name));
    }

    for(j = 0;j<3;j++){
        free(p[j].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof`is *not a function*. It is a language construct that resolves the size at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `p[i].name` is a `char *`, that is, a pointer to character(s). The size of a pointer to characters on your platform is 8 characters. So `sizeof(p[i].name)` returns 8.

Note that *the size of an object has nothing to do with its value*. So that `p[i].name` points to someplace that has 12 characters in it has no effect on the size of `p[i].name` itself.

Think how odd it would be if doing `p[i].name = NULL;` changed the *size* of `p[i].name`. Those 12 characters are still the same size and `p[i].name` still have four characters holding the `NULL`.

When you allocate space for an object, you do that before you know its value. So the size can't depend on the value.